# Change the folder structure in drupal 9 project

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-9

I have created the new project in drupal 9 now my project folder looks like project_name/web.
I need to run my project as project_name.I have dpwnloaded my drupal package with composer.
How to run the project as project_name.
I have tried copying

vendor,
.editorconfig,
.gitattributes,
composer.json,
composer.lock

to the root folder and rename web as project_name.but not working.

Comment: Is this change because of a hosting limitation?

Comment: no by basic download getting the this folder structure

Comment: If you are using composer, then you can change the name of the sub-directory in the composer.json file. Some info here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies . But I would point out that it's very common to use the "web" directory, and not change the name to something specific for the project name.